# invalid operands to binary +

Tags: c++, c, binary

i have some code like:

```
u=(float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));

for(i=1; i<n; i++)
{
*(u+n)=dr*(*(u+n-1))-(dr*20)+(*(u+n-2));
*(u+i)=k1*(pow(*(u+i+1),2)+pow(*(u+i-1),2)-2*(*(u+i+1))*(*(u+i-1)))+(k2*(*(u+i))+k3)*(*(u+i+1)-2*(*(u+i))+(*(u+i-1)))+(k2*(*(u+i))+(k3/i)-k4)*(*(u+i+1)-(*(u+i-1)));

}
```

i have this error:(invalid operands to binary + )in third line
what should i do?

Comment: Seriously now, is this question a joke question? Maybe you want to use more meaningful variable names

Comment: First and most obvious: break that line up into smaller pieces, so the compiler can/will give you a more specific error message.

Comment: Break up the calculations into multiple lines.

Comment: Also - I don't think the downvotes are called for.  Yes this is terrible `c`, but plenty of people from math/science backgrounds write code like this.  They'll never learn if the programming community shuns them rather than teaching.

Comment: You use almost no whitespace which is even more confusing, and why are you using the dereference operator when you will have so many multiplications? just use `u[i]` and the equivalents, it's way better, don't you think?

Comment: Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `u=(float *)calloc(n, sizeof(float));`  Then you have this: `*(u+n)=...`  Looks like an out-of-bounds access violation to me.

Comment: @Brian McFarland: I do think a downvote is called for. The question is not precise. The code doesn't show the definition of involved variables. Further it doesn't show the exact error.

Comment: When I grab a copy of your code, wrap it in a `main` function with `#include` directives for `<math.h>` and `<stdlib.h>`, and add declarations: `float *u; int i, n, k1, k2, k3, k4, dr;`, I don't get the error you report. The third line of the code in your question is `for(i=1; i<n; i++)`; there is no `+` operator on that line, so I'm skeptical that you'd get that particular message. Update your question to show a complete self-contained program that produces that error message when compiled.

Comment: @Keith - +1 for a good comment

Comment: Apart from the other problems with your code, using indexing notation would probably make it clearer. For example, `*(u+n)` is more clearly (and equivalently) written as `u[n]`.

Comment: is `i` or `n` a float number?

Comment: @mch: If `i` or `n` were floating-point, the code wouldn't compile. We know `u` is a pointer, and pointer+floating addition is invalid. (But in a properly posed question, we'd see the declarations and wouldn't have to ask.)

Comment: Using `pow()` to compute the square of a number is likely to be inefficient and potentially imprecise. The `pow()` function has to allow for both operands being non-integer values. Multiplying a number by itself is faster and less error-prone. A macro like `#define SQUARE(x) ((x)*(x))` can be useful (but be aware that the argument is evaluated twice, so don't apply it to something with side effects). Or just store the operand in a variable and then multiply that variable by itself. Or define an `inline` function.

Comment: @KeithThompson i thought it is a compile time error. There is no information about where the error occured.

Answer (score 0):

First of all - you must provide more details! For instance - which line is the third line? How is n defined? How is dr defined?

Anyway:

```
*(u+n)=dr*(*(u+n-1))-(dr*20)+(*(u+n-2));
```

is for sure a bad thing.

```
*(u+n)
```

is outside the memory allocated.

But that doesn't explain a compile error.

Comment: Yes, but that doesn't explain the compile-time error.

Comment: @Keith - TRUE - that is why I'm asking for more information. I'm pretty sure the compile error says more than just "invalid operands to binary +".

Comment: LOL - downvoted for pointing out a serious problem in the code!

Comment: No, downvoted for not answering the question. The problem you point out would be a good comment -- which PaulMcKenzie posted before you posted your answer.

Comment: @Keith - OK - point taken - but that is kind of what happens... while writing an answer and investigating the code, you don't see all comments/answers posted by others. Anyway - from the start I didn't state that my answer only pointed to a bug in the code - not the real problem. I should have done that!

Comment: My point is that the question was about the "invalid operands to binary +" message. If you don't answer *that question*, you shouldn't post an answer. If somebody else's comment hadn't already covered the issue you discuss, I would have suggested that you post a comment instead of an answer.  (As it happens, the question is unanswerable given the current state of the question -- which is why I downvoted the question as well, and I've also just voted to close it.)

Answer (score 0):

If I declare `n` or `i` as float, I am getting the same error.

http://ideone.com/h75svr

So the answer to your question is:

Every variable that you want to add to a pointer must be of an integer type.

```
int i;
int n;
```

in your case. All other variables can be `float`.